# Impossible to download VM on Modern.IE

Tags: download, virtual-machine, modern.ie

Something is broken on https://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/

After selecting the VM that I want to download, the links do not appear...

And there is a js error in my console log...

> ReferenceError: i18n is not defined

Comment: I can reproduce this problem as well, very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue.
I have found this gist with the direct links to the downloads: 
https://gist.github.com/zmwangx/e728c56f428bc703c6f6

Only mac links but maybe the others can be built from the structure.

Answer (score 0):

This [Github project](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms) has the VMs available through a bash script. I'm trying to download one now, and it appears to be working. Appears to work on multiple platforms.

Comment: Main website also appears to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed since around 7.00am PST.
The issue was a missing file in the CDN that didn't get pushed (`i18next\i18next.js`).